# Angular JS slide animation rendering

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to implement a nested slide animation.

For now the controller is just faking an update to the scope after pressing the Set buttons:

```
<div class="well" style="height: 270px;">

  <div ng-if="setCard=='one'" class="panel panel-default slidey">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span ng-repeat="thing in things">
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="things.selected=thing.id">{{thing.name}}</button>  
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"  style="height: 170px;" ng-init="things.selected=1">
      <div ng-repeat="thing in things">
        <div id="{{thing.id}}" ng-if="things.selected == thing.id" class="slidey">
          <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/animals/{{thing.id}}/" alt="thing.name">
          {{thing.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="setCard=='two'" class="panel panel-default slidey">   
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span ng-repeat="thing in things">
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="things.selected=thing.id">{{thing.name}}</button>  
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"  style="height: 170px;" ng-init="things.selected=3">
      <div ng-repeat="thing in things">
        <div id="{{thing.id}}" ng-if="things.selected == thing.id" class="slidey">
          <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/animals/{{thing.id}}/" alt="thing.name">
          {{thing.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tp55OtdtUGDl7exabBWB?p=preview)

The animations work as planned, but the rendering is brutal. Even when hard-coding the panel body height, it doesnt stay constant during the slide. and the whole thing is flickering. Is this an issue with the code or browser rendering?

Comment: give [css animations](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) a shot, typically css animates much better than js and works on mobile better as well

Comment: @hagope that looks really nice! but, my example is ultimately css animation based on class slidey, no?

Comment: not sure what slidey is, a JS plugin? Also, try [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) if you want to use Angular to your advantage